# Rewriting rules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Let's assume that we have the address `www.address.com` and we want to redirect that address to `www.example.com/address`.

After redirecting `www.address.com` to `www.example.com/address`, we do not want the user to notice the change in the url and rewrite `www.example.com/address` to  `www.address.com`.

Is there a way to achieve that. Thanks!

Comment: If both domains refer to the same vhost, then you could probably do that with an internal rewrite. If they aren’t, then you would need to set up a _reverse proxy_.

Comment: #misorude Both domains are hosted by the same company, if that is what you mean. If so, How to write the internal rewrite?